# Excel: Strange behavior related to INDIRECT pointed to itself

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2013

Using Excel 2013 ...

I was playing around with the INDIRECT function and found a very strange sequence of results. It occurs when I place the INDIRECT function in a cell (for example, A2) and ask for that cell (for example, =INDIRECT("A2")).

So if I start like this, typing the formula shown into B2, I get "0." (Row 1 has the FORMULATEXT function to display what is in row 2. C2 shows which cell INDIRECT is pointing to.) This is **not** what I expected.

[image]

Then if I change the value in B3 to 3, I get what I expected in B2:

[image: Step 2]

If I change B3 back to 2, the value displayed in B2 remains unchanged. This is the value I thought I would see in the first step.

[image: Step 3]

If I click in the formula bar at B2 and press Enter, the 0 reappears, and we're back to the original.

I get the same results if I change the argument to INDIRECT manually (from "A2" to "A3" and back).

It seems like it would be bad practice to ask for an indirect reference to the cell INDIRECT appears in, but this behavior looks kind of buggy to me. B2 is just producing a text string, so where did the original "0" come from?

Any explanation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are creating a circular reference and as such the default return is `0`.

So when B3 is 2 and it points at itself it becomes 0 and stops the calculations and all calculations dependent on it.  Which is why the next formula does not change till you force it by entering and exiting edit mode.

You continue to get `0` when pointing at A3 because it is empty and an empty cell equates to `0`.

Comment: So the two instances differ, even though the result is 0 in both cases. Anyway, you're saying that when B3 = 2, the circular reference prevents the formula in B2 from recalculating, right?

Comment: yes, when looking at A2 it is circular and causes the calculations to stop.  And when it is A3 it is looking at a blank cell and as such returns an actual `0`